# How to omit lines from php output

Tags: php, bash

I want to execute gotty top -c command using php. On shell Gotty gives below outout of command

```
2017/12/12 17:09:45 GoTTY is starting with command: top -c
2017/12/12 17:09:45 HTTP server is listening at: http://:::8080/
2017/12/12 17:09:45 Alternative URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/
2017/12/12 17:09:45 Alternative URL: http://::1:8080/
2017/12/12 17:09:45 Alternative URL: http://88.198.110.71:8080/
```

On browser I would like to show http://88.198.110.71:8080/ URL only.

I tried to get this using below code but its not working for me

```
$output = shell_exec('/bin/gotty top -c');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

How can I get output of this using php ?

Comment: You will want to explain and show what "not working for me" means in the body of the question.

Comment: What is the error or what is returned to you?

Comment: Have you tried parsing the output you got in `$output`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `grep` to get what you want.  As a default it will return complete lines, but if you pass option `-o`, then `o`nly the matched part is returned:

```
/bin/gotty top -c | grep -o 'http://.*'
```

This will print

```
http://:::8080/
http://127.0.0.1:8080/
http://::1:8080/
http://88.198.110.71:8080/
```

To have just the last line in the output, you could use `tail`:

```
/bin/gotty top -c | grep -o 'http://.*' | tail -1
```

Output:

```
http://88.198.110.71:8080/
```

Comment: Hello.. Thanks I am getting on this in outout 

[root@ssd /]# /bin/gotty top -c | grep -o 'http://.*' | tail -1
2017/12/12 17:26:29 GoTTY is starting with command: top -c

Comment: Looks like you only see the message given to stderr upon starting GoTTY (that `... is starting with ...` stuff).  If the output of your command doesn't contain any `http://`, you will get no output at all.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are this output only goes to STDERR so you will need to redirect to STDOUT. In addition, if you only want the last line of output, `exec()` command makes that easy to get.

```
<?php
$last_line = exec("/bin/gotty top -c 2>&1", $full_output, $exit_status);
echo "<pre>$last_line</pre>";
```